# Integrating OSuser with spring and hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate

What are the configuration I have to do in order to use `OSuser`in Spring with Hibernate.I know `OSuser` provides hibernate providers but how can I configure it inside spring.Please explain in detail if anybody knows.